# TypeScript generic function definition with "array" and "member of array" parameters

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define a generic function that receives 2 parameters:

- First parameter is an array of distinct strings (union of string literals)
- Second parameter is a member of the first parameter

```
// something like:
function showTab<T>(options: T[], selected: T) {
   options.forEach(option => { ... });
}
```

How can I get Intellisense to help narrow my second parameter?

```
showTab(["Home", "About", "Contact"], "           // as I type this,
                                       ^ Home     // I want these suggestions
                                       ^ About
                                       ^ Contact
```

Have a feeling this should be doable with a clever mix of `as const` and `infer` directives, but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want this function to be able to receive string arrays you can do this.

```
function showTab<TItem extends string, T extends Array<TItem>>(options: T, selected: T[number]) {}
```

Then you will receive the desired autocomplete because in your example infered type will be `"Home" | "About" | "Contact"`. And you will get error if you try to choose selectedItem that is not in the array

Answer (score 0):

The strict way to only have options is to use read-only arrays as bellow:

```
function showTab<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>>(options: T, selected: T[keyof T]) { }

const array = ['hello', 'mello'] as const;
const array2 = ['hello', 'mello', 5] as const;

showTab(array, 'hello');
showTab(array2, 'hello');
showTab(array2, 5);

showTab(array, 'hell'); // Error
showTab(array2, '3'); // Error
showTab(array2, 'hell'); // Error
```

TS playground here: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwBZwO4BUCGAjAHi0QFMAPKEsAE2UQCUSdqEAbATwEEAnbndgjjDsAfCIAUcAA6wEyAFyIsAGhQlWJaCWqKsAbQDWJdnGBKAugEpEAb0QBfAFCOIcqIhy9%20iALyI9AOSo6qxwAaoBALYhYeYedK5gyFAA3C5uHl7sAEy%20-kEx4YhRhaoArHE4CW5pjmiYuHjinnzsEcGsoQGWdejY%20M1Z2e0h3UA)

The reason is that the value lookup only works on static arrays, they can be achieved in multiple ways and the easiest it to use read-only array. Also, the readonlyness should complement your code, as the tabs might not change anyway.